# swift-- Variable button action

Tags: swift

I would like to ask a simple question : 
how can I give a variable to the action in the creation of a button ?

if for create the button use :

```
 newButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

on Object-c i did

```
NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button%d:",index+1];

[newButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(selectorName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and on Swift ?

Answer (score 1):

use NSSelectorFromString

```
let sel = NSSelectorFromString("Button\(index+1)")

newButton.addTarget(self, action: sel, forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store Swift Selector structs as a variable.

```
let sel : Selector = "buttonTapped:"
button.addTarget(self, action: sel)
```

If you want the selector to have a variable in it, you can simply add the variable to the string like this:

```
let sel : Selector = "button\(buttonNumber)tapped"
```

This makes use of Selector's adoption of the StringLiteralConvertible.

Selectors are mentioned in the [Using Swift With Objective C ebook](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_38).